IIS and ASP.NET Core web app: AD auto-login fail
I'm currently trying to build an ASP.NET Core web app on an IIS server (Windows Server 2012 with AD). This app should have an auto login for the AD user and an automatic redirection for the other user.
On IIS server, I enabled the Windows authentication and anonymous authentication. But, when I test my app, the browser always ask me for my credentials twice, even though I'm currently logged into AD.
Here is my program.cs:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration;


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services
       .AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
       .AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

builder.Services
       .AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

builder.Services
       .AddDbContext<LogContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("constring"), o => o.UseCompatibilityLevel(120)));

builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

builder.Services
       .AddSession(options =>
                   {
                       options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                       options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                       options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                   });

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseSession();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Log}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();

And here's the code that check if the user is connected and ask for his AD user if needed:
public async Task<bool> SessionStart(HttpContext httpContext) 
{
    bool result = false;

    // Check if we have a session
    string  login = httpContext.Session.GetString("Login") ?? "";

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(login)) 
    {
        result = true;
        this._isAD = httpContext.Session.GetString("isAd") == "true";
    }
    // else, we try to auto connect to AD
    else
    {
        ActiveDirectory AD = new ActiveDirectory(domainName, domainUsername, domainPassword);

        // we check AD connection
        if (AD.TestConnection())
        {
            // We send the authentication demand
            await httpContext.ChallengeAsync(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            AuthenticateResult? authenticationResult = await httpContext.AuthenticateAsync(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            if (authenticationResult != null && authenticationResult.Succeeded)
            {
                string currentUsername = authenticationResult.Principal?.Identity?.Name ?? "Anonymous";

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentUsername))
                {
                    // We get the windows user and check if is in the AD group for app access
                    if (AD.IsUserInGroup(currentUsername, Session.domaineComplet))
                    {
                        httpContext.Session.SetString("Login", currentUsername);
                        httpContext.Session.SetString("Group", Session.domaineComplet);
                        httpContext.Session.SetString(key: "isAd", "true");
                    }
                    else if (AD.IsUserInGroup(currentUsername, Session.domaineBasic))
                    {
                        httpContext.Session.SetString("Login", currentUsername);
                        httpContext.Session.SetString("Group", Session.domaineBasic);
                        httpContext.Session.SetString(key: "isAd", "true");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // not connected
                        result = false;
                    }
                }
            } 
            else
            {
                // authentication failed
            }
        }
        else
        {
           // AD not connected
        }
    }

    return result;
}

Can anyone help, please?

Update:
After further testing, we found out that we didn't parameter correctly the two browsers (we forgot the AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist for Chrome and negotiate-auth.trusted-uris for Firefox).
After these have been corrected, Firefox works correctly, but Chrome asks us for credentials, and if we cancel it, we get connected to the app anyway.

what happen after you enter credential for second time / does it allow you to access the site or it is giving some error? what is the error ode logged in the iis log should you please share with us? how you have set the providers for windows authentication? could you try to disable anonymous authentication in iis? could you try to add your domain local internet trusted site list in IE setting. also set "Automatic logon with current user name and password" in User Authentication.

@JalpaPanchal
The browser weren't configured correctly on the server for auto logon (I updated the question).
For your other question: window authentication has Negotiate and NTLM providers.

make sure you have set the windows auth to enable and anonymous to disable in iis and add your site to the AuthServerWhitelist for chrome. and set middleware in program.cs file in this order : app.UseHttpsRedirection();    app.UseStaticFiles();    app.UseRouting();    app.UseSession();    app.UseAuthentication();    app.UseAuthorization();
